# Unity IOS build error in xCode at Admob library

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

I got the 30 errors when build by Xcode. This is a sample. I guess problem is googleadlibrary but I can't resolve it.

```
  "_GADUShowRewardBasedVideoAd", referenced from:


  _Externs_GADUShowRewardBasedVideoAd_m892979392 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o


  _RewardBasedVideoAdClient_ShowRewardBasedVideoAd_m553031711 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUShowRewardBasedVideoAd_m892979392)
```

I also added libraries as below image. Please help me resolve the errors
[image]

Comment: I encounter the same issue. Still fighting against it.

Comment: please try to add library for google ad. I forgot where we can download it. I am finding it

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start